# Every time there's a new notification, my component does not recognize it

Tags: reactjs, laravel-echo

i take care of frontend part using ReactJS of a Laravel project. Currently i implement the notifications with using Laravel Echo Server. I render and update State well  but the problem is every time there's a new notification, my component does not recognize it. Here is my Notifications component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Echo from "laravel-echo";

class Notifications extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userLogin: {}
    };

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.post(laroute.route('api.get-users'))
      .then(res=>{
        this.setState({
          userLogin:res.data.userLogin
        });
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
      })

    window.Echo.private('users.' + this.state.userLogin.id)
      .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification);
      });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
          Notifications
      </span>
    )
  }
}

export default Notifications;
```

I tried to change ComponentDidMount to ConmponentWillMount but it still not working for the notification. Funny thing is that if i put those Listening For Notifications inside blade template, it works well:

```
@section('header')
 ....
@endsection

@section('after-scripts')
    <script>

        var userId= "{{ access()->user()->id  }}";
        window.Echo.private('users.' + userId)
            .notification((notification) => {
                console.log(notification);
            });
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with larvel, but I see you make a window.Echo.private('users.' + this.state.userLogin.id) , I'm sure your problem there is no userLogin to read id;

Comment: to fix this move this part into .then of your axios.post request.

Comment: Either you can move window.Echo.private inside .then or use lifecycle method componentWillReceiveProps that will invoke once props/state gets updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.post` would result in a value asynchronously. But your `window.Echo.private` would run before that. Move it inside and check if it works.

Here, give this a try:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.post(laroute.route('api.get-users'))
    .then(res => {
      const { userLogin } = res.data;
      window.Echo.private('users.' + userLogin.id)
        .notification(notification => console.log(notification));
      this.setState({
        userLogin
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```